# New at jquery, having problems with passing arguments to use in a selector

Tags: jquery, arguments, selector

I need some help passing arguments to a jquery function. I have an html header, with

```
onclick="slide(#aboutit);"
```

and I created, in the header, a function

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function slide(element){
        var slid = element;
        slid.slideToggle("slow");
    }
</script>
```

for some reason which I don't understand, this isn't working. I can get it do work if instead of that I use

```
function slide(){
    $('#aboutit').slideToggle("slow");
}
```

but I don't want to have to create a new function for sliding for each part of the website.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code `slide(#aboutit);` is invalid.  What you can do instead is `slide($('#aboutit'))`.

Answer (score 0):

With jQuery you use the document ready function to load items when the DOM is drawn. Then place all the items within the document.ready() function.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function() {


    $('#aboutit').slideToggle("slow");

    $('#anotherdiv').slideToggle("slow");

    $('#yetanotherdiv').slideToggle("slow");


});
</script>
```

The above assumes you are calling the jquery core before running the document.ready() function.

You will most likely want some other function for the slideToggle though. Otherwise your content simply slide on page load. IF that's what you want. great. If you want to to slide on a click you need to call a click function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function() {


    $('#aboutit').click(function(){
       $(this).slideToggle("slow");
     });


});
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks, but no need for checking if the DOM is ready, since I call it on an onCLick event, and as for the rest of it goes, correcting my code is simpler. Thanks though, never reject a helping hand!

Answer (score 0):

I know you've already accepted an answer that corrected the two problems with your code (the unquoted string and the fact that your `slide()` function was expecting a jQuery object not a string), but since you mentioned this:

> I don't want to have to create a new function for sliding for each part of the website

Instead of coding an `onclick` for each element that you want to slide where you have to individually specify the id of the element as in your current code:

```
onclick="slide($('#elementid'));"
```

Your code would be much simpler and easier to maintain if you instead assigned a common class to all the elements (no matter what their type) that you want to slide on, like so:

```
<h1 class="slideMe">A heading</h1>
<div class="slideMe">A div</div>
<h2 class="slideMe otherclass">Note elements can have multiple classes</h2>
<p class="slideMe">And so on and so forth</p>
```

Because then you can apply the slide functionality to *all* of them by writing a single line of code to assign a click handler based on that class. Needs to be in a document.ready (or at the end of the body):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".slideMe").click(function() {
         $(this).slideToggle("slow");
    });
});
```

Notice that this is barely longer than your existing `slide()` function. When an individual item is clicked it will slide. Easy.

Notice also that if you then add additional elements that need to slide you don't have to give them an `id` attribute and then match up the `onclick` to call `slide()` with that `id`, you simply add the "slideMe" class and it'll happen automatically.